# How to filter the contents of a list?

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

I use two List data, one must call the other for parameter, but I can not implement a filter to the data you desire.

This contest is for this Listing:

```
   @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/listarReceita/{controle}/versoes")
public String listVersions(@PathVariable("controle") int controle, Map<String, Object> map) {

    map.put("versoesList", receitaService.getAllReceita());    

    return "listVersions";
}
```

But in this case, the result is the entire contents of the table. This is not what I want. What I want to see only the data with the content parameter passed in the case "control."

How could I solve this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to recieve only the related values, you have to create a method in recietaService  `list getRecietaByControle(int controle) { }`  and implement the logic to create query to pull up the recieta.

Now the above mentioned method calls this new method to get only those elements which match the criteria, instead of getting all from db

Comment: Hi Akash Yadav, precious reply! :D
Thus the listed data will be restricted only to the value of the parameter "controle"?

Comment: Just implement, the result was all the same data. : S
I did so: `public List getControle_versao(int controle){       
         return session.getCurrentSession().createQuery("from Receita").list();
    }`.And the controller, like this:` @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="/listarReceita/{controle}/versoes")
    public String listVersions(@PathVariable("controle") int controle, Map<String, Object> map){
        map.put("versoesList", receitaService.getControle_versao(controle));  
        return "listVersions";
    }`.There is something that is not right? Thanks for the great help.